# Some database logic, retrieving correct entries

Tags: java, android, sql, database

So a little detail on what I'm trying to do first. 
I have an online game system where a user writes a word, this gets posted to a database with some values. This all works fine.

Here's a database entry example:

```
uniqueID   victim      rival    wordguess   won
   6      607260120   504374351     Gg       0
```

Now the problem, many victims can start games against many rivals, how does a victim check that they have a game initiated against them, and that they have initiated a game against an person?

I have two PHP files that are currently used to check these things with these lines:

```
$query = "SELECT `rival` FROM currentgames WHERE `victim` = '$victim'";
echo $row["rival"].",";
```

And the opposite way around for victims.

Now in my Java I'm checking the current value in a listarray adapter like so:

```
for (int i = 0;i<NetPlay.rivalArray.length-1;i++)
        {
            Log.i("VICTIM ARRAY DATA ", NetPlay.rivalArray[i]);

            if (NetPlay.rivalArray[i].equals(f.id))
            {
                ingame = true;
                break;

            }
            else
            {
                ingame = false;

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0;i<NetPlay.victimArray.length-1;i++)
        {
            Log.i("RIVAL ARRAY DATA ", NetPlay.victimArray[i]);

            if (NetPlay.victimArray[i].equals(NetPlay.myId))
            {
                battle = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                battle = true;

            }

        }

        if (battle.equals(false))
        {
            battleBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else 
        {
            battleBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (ingame.equals(true))
        {
            newgameBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else 
        {
            newgameBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Oddly, I can get players to show whether or not they have already initialised a match against an opponent, thus hiding the "new game" button, but I am unable to get the Accept Game button to work properly.
Databases and SQL are definitely my weak point and I really can't figure out a proper way to work this out. An initial idea was to give each User/Victim their own Table within the database, however then poses the problem of checking games against them within other UserId's tables, would get messy very fast.

I should probably also add this is going on inside a listview Adapter, so f.id changes for each listview item, these checks also happen for each and every listview adapter, I realise this isn't very efficient but my main focus is getting it to work and then optimising from there.

Also to note, I have the "New Game" button working perfectly, I assumed the second button would be pretty much the same kind of thing but no matter which way around I work it, it doesn't work, I'm sure its something I'm just overlooking.
Any ideas guys?

Ok I have narrowed it down to the fact that the SQL statement for the checking if a game has been initiated against you by this person is returning nothing, so that's obviously where I've gone wrong but I just can't figure out what is wrong, I've tried all sorts!

Comment: So what's happening?  Is the Accept Game button always showing up even after the game is accepted?

Comment: In your PHP script, did you remove some of your code? Just making sure, because if you did, nothing would be outputted, all you did was create a string.

Comment: Yeh I didn't include all the code just the parts I thought were relevant, it all works fine, just doesn't work as expected, the issue is that a "Accept Battle" button should appear to accept a game someones started against you, however no matter what I do I can't get it to display properly, i either have it display for everyone or hide for everyone, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't select all players someone's already playing against. Instead, query something like:

```
SELECT `uniqueID` 
FROM currentgames 
WHERE (`victim` = '$victim' AND `rival` = '$rival')
OR (`victim` = '$rival' AND `rival` = '$victim');
```

This way, you either get a row coming back or you don't, and you don't need to check through the rows returned to see if one of the rows is a problem. This should make things a lot easier for your Accept logic too.

Comment: So this would get the Unique ID for that individual game then? I'm not sure that this would fix it though since it's pretty similar to what I've already got going on, just this is much more efficient

Comment: Ok. So what is the condition you need to find for the "Accept" button to work. Is it that you need to have found a game, but that some other field has a particular value to indicate the game hasn't been accepted yet?

Comment: Once the game is finished it is deleted from the database for now, so there's no issue with detecting whether its been accepted, simple wether it exists.
I'm currently doing a check for
if rivalid = currentrivalid (in the list view) AND if victimID = myID 
However it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: So... someone propses a game, and someone else accepts it. What happens in the database between those two events? Answer that and it might help you find the problem.

Comment: Someone proposes a game, sets a word, these values are then stored ina database with:
Victim (opponent) Rival (their id) Word
Then another player loads up the app, and the app checks the database to see if anyone has challenged them with any new words by checking something like:
is my ID in the victim field? AND is their ID in the rival field?
Yes, ok assign the button to visible, else hide it
I hope that makes more sense?
That is the PHP/SQL snippet I've added, I can add more code if you think that would be beneficial?

Comment: So then once they guess the word the row in the database gets deleted?

Comment: Yeh that's not handled yet, it doesn't even get that far, but that is what will happen eventually

Comment: So - is the problem simply that you need an array of ingame/battle? Currently those are single variables, when it sounds like you need an array, with a value for each rival.

Comment: No that isn't necessary as this is all called within a listview adapter, so the ingame/battle variables are changed for each item in the listview, so the button code for hidden/visible is done for every single list item individually, I know that's hardly efficient but I just want it to work at the moment